# How to determine the limit of a squence?

Tags: limits

I have a question in respect to the following sequence:

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

I would say that because the denominator is growing much faster that the numerator the sequence converges at $0$. However, I dont understand the notation inf...does it have any impact on the conclusion?

Comment: Is it perhaps $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$? The lonesome $\inf$ doesn't really make sense.

Comment: yes, I thought it makes no difference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: the sequence converges, to $0$. So in this case, $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$ are the same as $\lim$.

This is not generally true. For example, the sequence $((-1)^n)$ doesn't converge, but $\lim \inf (-1)^n = -1$ (and $\lim \sup (-1)^n = 1$).

Answer (score 0):

Well,
$$
\left| \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right| = \frac{1}{n} \to 0.
$$
Hence the sequence converges to zero.